# Jquery Validate Form very slow in IE 8

Tags: internet-explorer-8, jquery-validate

I have a large form and on submit I am trying the validate the form using jquery as $(".form").validate().form() and on IE 8 it takes around 20182ms and on chrome it takes 1800ms.

This makes the application unresponsive and slow.

Is there a way to improve the speed for validation?

The form content are loaded using jquery $.get method as below code.

```
        $.get(url, paramData, function (data) {
            $("#eCheckList .content-body").html(data);
            $.validator.unobtrusive.parse($(".eCheckList-section form"));
        });
```

Here is the code to save the form.

```
    console.time("#Form Validation");
    var isValid = $(".eCheckList-section form").valid();
    console.timeEnd("#Form Validation");

    if (isValid) {
        $("#container").addClass("ui-loading");
        var formData = $(".eCheckList-section form").serialize();
        $.post(url, formData, function (response) {
        });            
    }
```

Here is the example in jsfiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/w9Lq9/3/

As jsfiddle - I am unable to test above link in IE8 but here is the times for different browser that i tested and chrome performance was worst.

Chrome

ParseForm : 3159ms 
FormValidate: 2839ms

IE 9

ParseForm : 106ms 
FormValidate: 848ms

IE 11

ParseForm : 172ms 
FormValidate: 1266ms

Firefox

ParseForm: 272ms 
FormValidate: 611ms

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing your full code, it's impossible to say for sure what you're doing wrong.

However, the `.validate()` method is typically only used to *initialize* the plugin on your form, and only gets called once on page load.

If you want to trigger a *test* of the form, you would use the `.valid()` method.

```
$(".form").valid();
```

See if that improves anything.

Comment: Updated Code available